# How to filter by embedded object field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

Here is my search object:

```
{
    "_index": "search",
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "2",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "datePublished": "2014-01-01T00:00:00-08:00",
        "published": true,
        "name": "Winter Coat",
        "description": "A nice warm winter coat.  If you get cold with this on, you've probably done something wrong.",
        "brand": {
            "name": "Burton"
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the query i'm trying to perform:

```
$query = new Query\QueryString('*' . 'winter' .'*');
$boolFilter = new Bool();
$brandFilter = new Term(['brand.name' => 'Burton']);
$boolFilter->addMust($brandFilter);
$filtered = new Filtered($baseQuery, $boolFilter);
return Query::create($filtered);
```

but i'm getting nothing back.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error i found that terms is a somewhat unreliable way to do exact matching because of the tokenizer.  For any field you want to exact match you need to make sure it is not analyzed.  Alternatively, you can just use integer values (such and an object id) for exact matching.  I ended up using ids in the cases of exact matching.